# GStreamer plugin search path?

Tags: c, gstreamer

Can I somehow tell GStreamer to look for plugins in a specified directory?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable to point at the directory you want, or programatically just call:

```
GstRegistry *registry;
registry = gst_registry_get();
gst_registry_scan_path(registry, directory);
```

Comment: `gst_registry_get_default()` was replaced with `gst_registry_get()` ,  `gst_registry_add_path()` COULD be replaced with  `gst_registry_scan_path()`

Answer (score 6):

You can no longer do this programmatically in gstreamer 1.0.

In the above answer,

`gst_registry_get_default()` was replaced with `gst_registry_get()`
and `gst_registry_add_path()` was removed.

You can also set `GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH` to the location of the Plugins. Not sure what the difference is between this and `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` though.

Comment: In GStreamer 1.0 there is a function gst_registry_add_plugin () https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstregistry.html?gi-language=c#gst_registry_add_plugin

Comment: In GStreamer 1.0 there is a function `gst_registry_scan_path()` :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you are running GStreamer from command line you may add **--gst-plugin-path=PATHS** to the command

Example adding current directory as plugins path

```
gst-inspect-1.0 kvssink --gst-plugin-path=$PWD
```

There is much more useful commands available just check:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --help-gst
```